# Logitech's LED Illumination SDK is not working with my G502

Tags: c#, led, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to get [Logitech's own LED SDK](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/developers) working with my G502, but I can't.
I'm using SDK version 8.82.7, which is, as of now, the most recent version. I also couldn't find anything on SO or the rest of the internet, so I'm asking here.

Here's my LogitechGSDK.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LogiRGB {

    public enum KeyboardNames {
        ESC = 0x01,
        F1 = 0x3b,
        F2 = 0x3c,
        F3 = 0x3d,
        F4 = 0x3e,
        F5 = 0x3f,
        F6 = 0x40,
        F7 = 0x41,
        F8 = 0x42,
        F9 = 0x43,
        F10 = 0x44,
        F11 = 0x57,
        F12 = 0x58,
        PRINT_SCREEN = 0x137,
        SCROLL_LOCK = 0x46,
        PAUSE_BREAK = 0x45,
        TILDE = 0x29,
        ONE = 0x02,
        TWO = 0x03,
        THREE = 0x04,
        FOUR = 0x05,
        FIVE = 0x06,
        SIX = 0x07,
        SEVEN = 0x08,
        EIGHT = 0x09,
        NINE = 0x0A,
        ZERO = 0x0B,
        MINUS = 0x0C,
        EQUALS = 0x0D,
        BACKSPACE = 0x0E,
        INSERT = 0x152,
        HOME = 0x147,
        PAGE_UP = 0x149,
        NUM_LOCK = 0x145,
        NUM_SLASH = 0x135,
        NUM_ASTERISK = 0x37,
        NUM_MINUS = 0x4A,
        TAB = 0x0F,
        Q = 0x10,
        W = 0x11,
        E = 0x12,
        R = 0x13,
        T = 0x14,
        Y = 0x15,
        U = 0x16,
        I = 0x17,
        O = 0x18,
        P = 0x19,
        OPEN_BRACKET = 0x1A,
        CLOSE_BRACKET = 0x1B,
        BACKSLASH = 0x2B,
        KEYBOARD_DELETE = 0x153,
        END = 0x14F,
        PAGE_DOWN = 0x151,
        NUM_SEVEN = 0x47,
        NUM_EIGHT = 0x48,
        NUM_NINE = 0x49,
        NUM_PLUS = 0x4E,
        CAPS_LOCK = 0x3A,
        A = 0x1E,
        S = 0x1F,
        D = 0x20,
        F = 0x21,
        G = 0x22,
        H = 0x23,
        J = 0x24,
        K = 0x25,
        L = 0x26,
        SEMICOLON = 0x27,
        APOSTROPHE = 0x28,
        ENTER = 0x1C,
        NUM_FOUR = 0x4B,
        NUM_FIVE = 0x4C,
        NUM_SIX = 0x4D,
        LEFT_SHIFT = 0x2A,
        Z = 0x2C,
        X = 0x2D,
        C = 0x2E,
        V = 0x2F,
        B = 0x30,
        N = 0x31,
        M = 0x32,
        COMMA = 0x33,
        PERIOD = 0x34,
        FORWARD_SLASH = 0x35,
        RIGHT_SHIFT = 0x36,
        ARROW_UP = 0x148,
        NUM_ONE = 0x4F,
        NUM_TWO = 0x50,
        NUM_THREE = 0x51,
        NUM_ENTER = 0x11C,
        LEFT_CONTROL = 0x1D,
        LEFT_WINDOWS = 0x15B,
        LEFT_ALT = 0x38,
        SPACE = 0x39,
        RIGHT_ALT = 0x138,
        RIGHT_WINDOWS = 0x15C,
        APPLICATION_SELECT = 0x15D,
        RIGHT_CONTROL = 0x11D,
        ARROW_LEFT = 0x14B,
        ARROW_DOWN = 0x150,
        ARROW_RIGHT = 0x14D,
        NUM_ZERO = 0x52,
        NUM_PERIOD = 0x53,
    };

    public static class LogitechGSDK {
        //LED SDK
        private const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_MONOCHROME_ORD = 0;
        private const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_RGB_ORD = 1;
        private const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_PERKEY_RGB_ORD = 2;

        public const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_MONOCHROME = (1 << LOGI_DEVICETYPE_MONOCHROME_ORD);
        public const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_RGB = (1 << LOGI_DEVICETYPE_RGB_ORD);
        public const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_PERKEY_RGB = (1 << LOGI_DEVICETYPE_PERKEY_RGB_ORD);
        public const int LOGI_DEVICETYPE_ALL = (LOGI_DEVICETYPE_MONOCHROME | LOGI_DEVICETYPE_RGB | LOGI_DEVICETYPE_PERKEY_RGB);

        public const int LOGI_LED_BITMAP_WIDTH = 21;
        public const int LOGI_LED_BITMAP_HEIGHT = 6;
        public const int LOGI_LED_BITMAP_BYTES_PER_KEY = 4;

        public const int LOGI_LED_BITMAP_SIZE = LOGI_LED_BITMAP_WIDTH * LOGI_LED_BITMAP_HEIGHT * LOGI_LED_BITMAP_BYTES_PER_KEY;
        public const int LOGI_LED_DURATION_INFINITE = 0;

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedInit();

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetTargetDevice(int targetDevice);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedGetSdkVersion(ref int majorNum, ref int minorNum, ref int buildNum);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSaveCurrentLighting();

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLighting(int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedRestoreLighting();

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedFlashLighting(int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage, int milliSecondsDuration, int milliSecondsInterval);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedPulseLighting(int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage, int milliSecondsDuration, int milliSecondsInterval);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedStopEffects();

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLightingFromBitmap(byte[] bitmap);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLightingForKeyWithScanCode(int keyCode, int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLightingForKeyWithHidCode(int keyCode, int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLightingForKeyWithQuartzCode(int keyCode, int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSetLightingForKeyWithKeyName(KeyboardNames keyCode, int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedSaveLightingForKey(KeyboardNames keyName);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedRestoreLightingForKey(KeyboardNames keyName);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedFlashSingleKey(KeyboardNames keyName, int redPercentage, int greenPercentage, int bluePercentage, int msDuration, int msInterval);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedPulseSingleKey(KeyboardNames keyName, int startRedPercentage, int startGreenPercentage, int startBluePercentage, int finishRedPercentage, int finishGreenPercentage, int finishBluePercentage, int msDuration, bool isInfinite);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool LogiLedStopEffectsOnKey(KeyboardNames keyName);

        [DllImport("LogitechLedEnginesWrapper ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void LogiLedShutdown();
    }
}
```

My color changing code basically amounts to

```
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedInit();
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetTargetDevice(LogitechGSDK.LOGI_DEVICETYPE_ALL);
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetLighting(255, 127, 0);
```

which *should* set my mouse's LEDs to a nice orange, but in reality does nothing.
It's worth noting that Logitech's own samples, which are included in the SDK .zip, do not work. I can set the LED color with Logitech's Gaming Software, but that's not what I want.

Is Logitech's SDK broken? If not, what can I do to get it working?

**Edit**: I should probably mention that I do own the RGB version of the G502.

Comment: did you checked if all the calls return true?

Comment: They do. The init method also correctly returns false if I call it multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

In your code the Arguments of `LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetLighting(255, 127, 0);` are incorrect as they exceed the value limitation.

They are supposed to be percentages not RGB values.

Enter a number between 0 and 100 for it to work.

Also replace your code:

```
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetTargetDevice(LogitechGSDK.LOGI_DEVICETYPE_ALL);
```

With:

```
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetTargetDevice(LogitechGSDK.LOGI_DEVICETYPE_RGB);
```

Or remove it all together.

Here is an example of orange:

```
LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetLighting(100, 30, 0);
```

Remember to give enough time for the code to initialize.