# Logitech G Hub - program LEDs on the g502?

Tags: c++, logitech

I am looking for a way to set the color/status of the LEDs on the Logitech G502 Lightspeed mouse dynamically from outside of GHUB.

To clarify my intent, I am running an autohotkey script to get multiple functions per button based on if the button was pressed for a short / intermediate / long amount of time. I just got this mouse and thought it would be very fancy if I could get the 3 DPI LEDs light up as I hold down a button for these set amount of times. I know C++ if that could be of help somehow .. as I saw it might be.

Unfortunately Logitechs G Hub Software only provides some very basic settings that are practically of no use ..

So first idea since I used to also manually edit the settings file of an older mouse was to try and change the settings.json files directly on the fly. While I can probably find where to edit the files, of course the settings do not update just by editing and saving the file and I am not sure **how or if that would be achievable**? If this could be done this seems like the easiest, though maybe a bit hacky, way to go about it.

At this point I am almost lost, I tried searching some more and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579302/logitechs-led-illumination-sdk-is-not-working-with-my-g502), which seemed promising at first but I am quite confused by the up-to-dateness of the solution. As far as I could tell the documentation of this SDK says it will only work with LGS. It seems G Hub did/was not exist/released at the date this was last updated, though it mentions an "early access version" of it on the download page. The documentation mentions the .dll from LGS is needed, which does not exist under the same name in G Hub. However there is a "sdk_legacy_led_x64.dll" in the install dir, which might or might not be something different .. I tried searching for the corresponding SDK, but in vain. So my second question(s) would be, **is this SDK, even if outdated, what I should use? And does it work with G Hub and the G502 (which does not show up in LGS); or is there a newer version I cannot find**?

Now I could try and see if this can somehow work / provides the functions I need, but as it seems not so simple and I'm not sure when I will have enough time to try I thought maybe someone here might have a better idea or already experience for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I found https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag, which is a Linux implementation of the led color switching. I suggest you either try to get it running on Windows, or study the internals and recreate the same using Windows libraries. Presumably you can get by with `libusb` or somesuch?